# How to set cron job for bi-weekly (twice a week)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

How do I set a cron job to run twice a week?

I know how to set a cron job for every week:

```
0 0 * * 0
```

Comment: does bi-weekly mean every other week, or twice a week - if it's every other week then please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350047/how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week

Answer (score 61, accepted):

How about the following:

```
0 0 * * 1,4
```

This sets the day of week to Monday (1) and Thursday (4). You can choose any values 0–7 (both 0 and 7 are Sunday).

For a more readable crontab, you can also use names:

```
0 0 * * MON,THU
```

*See also: [How to instruct cron to execute a job every second week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350047/how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week)*

Comment: I want to set cron for 2 times in a Month. Set cron for once at a 2 week

Comment: Biweekly is an ambiguous phrase; in the UK it tends to mean twice a week. For "every other week" we use *fortnightly* :-) See Petesh's comment above for a related question.

Answer (score 5):

In reply to Elby  question :

```
0 0 1,15 * *
```

This will set cronjob for (fortnight) 2 times in a Month i.e 1st day and 15th day of a month.

Answer (score 2):

These answers are great, but I wanted to share a tool I found right after looking at this question and answers called crontab.guru. I'm not affiliated, I just thought it was a nice tool.

[crontab.guru for 'At 00:00 on Monday and Thursday.'](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_*_1,4)