# Filter records by date based on date ranges assigned in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cron

I am setting up a scheduled cron job that launches a PHP script every other Monday.
My goal is to run a SQL query that returns work orders based on my company's pay period - each pay period ends on the Friday before I run this scheduled cron job.

I have a SQL table which lists all the pay periods of my company, so this table has two column: `payperiod_from` (start date range) and `payperiod_to` (end date range). The work orders that I am pulling have a date assigned to them. I would like to be able to pull the work orders where their date is between `payperiod_from` and `payperiod_to`.

Since pay periods end every other friday and this cron job is scheduled on the Monday after that, I can simply use `CURDATE() - 3` (3 days before Monday - Friday); to get the `payperiod_to` date, but how can I run a query that filters work orders who's date fall under the correct pay period?

Hopefully this makes sense to some of you guys.

Comment: Could you show some sample data and the desired output? Also, you should make an attempt to solve the problem yourself, and then we'll help you fix it -- we're not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may run into trouble trying to set up a cron job for "every other week". There's a StackOverflow answer about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/350061/2091410); note the comment under the answer.

As for selecting work orders whose date falls under the correct pay period, if you're already calculating the pay period end as three days before `CURDATE()` why not forget about the `pay_periods` table (or whatever it's named) and calculate the pay period beginning as 16 days before `CURDATE()`:

```
SELECT * FROM wkorder
WHERE wkorder.orderdate BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 16 DAY AND CURDATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

If you can't get the cron job to reliably run every other week and have to set it to weekly, then you can use the `pay_periods` table to filter out the off weeks. This will prevent any results if the prior Friday wasn't a pay-period end date because there won't be a match in the `pay_period` table:

```
SELECT * FROM wkorder
INNER JOIN pay_period ON
  payperiod_to = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND
  wkorder.orderdate BETWEEN pay_period.payperiod_from AND pay_period.payperiod_to
```

Finally, please note that the queries above are syntactically correct but they're not fully tested. It's too much of a leap to go from the information in the question to actual table structures.