# How to: Cron expression for multiple days on 2nd Week

Tags: cronexpression

I was wondering if it will be possible to build a cron expression for the following scenario:

**Occurs every 2 week(s) on Monday and Tuesday**. (I understand these options are not checked in the attached image)

[This is the requirement](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=74B6DC5B65B5E0C2!189)

I checked http://www.cronmaker.com/ "weekly" tab option, but it is missing an entry box to enter values.

Can you please assist if this can be achieved?

Thanks,
Hemant.

Comment: [duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350047/how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week)