# Using Crontab to schedule a task every other friday

Tags: unix, scheduled-tasks, cron

How would I use crontab to run a script at 5:30AM every other Friday in January? This is the what I have if I ran it every Friday.

```
30 5 * 1 5
```

If I did every other friday, where do i put the /2? Is it:

```
30 5 */2 1 5
```

or:

```
30 5 * 1 5/2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to instruct cron to execute a job every second week?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350047/how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week)

Answer (score 1):

check this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350047/how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week) but I would recommend using two crons one for the first week and second for the third week as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19276777/2833695).You could als use http://www.cronmaker.com/ to build crons.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
0 0 1-7,15-21 * 5
```

This is run 2 times a month, both on Fridays and at least a week apart.

Comment: This can backfire depending on the cron service. It executes at **00:00 on every day-of-month from 1 through 7 and every day-of-month from 15 through 21 and on Friday** on many services. Try different combos at [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_1-7,15-21_*_5).

Comment: @Richard it worked for me, still running on my production server, no issues till now.

I don't agree that it'll fail in any case.