# How to set a cron job to run once in two weeks on specific days of week

Tags: reactjs, cron

How do I set up a cron expression to run a cron job once in two weeks, on specific days of week.
Suppose the user selects Mon,Fri,Sat. I will have to run the job on those days of week and again after 2 weeks on the same Days.
The user input is developed in react, and I need to frame the expression depending on the input and send it to backend for the job to run

I'm using node-cron to parse the cron expression at backend: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Comment: I suppose you'll have to start by investigating cron all by yourself.

Comment: There are quite a few tools: https://www.google.com/search?q=create+cron+expression

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350047/how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260918/using-crontab-to-schedule-a-task-every-other-friday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109358/how-to-create-a-cron-expression-for-every-2-weeks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49812967/cron-expression-for-every-second-monday-of-the-month-for-hangfire