# How to schedule cron job every other week

Tags: cron

How to enable cron entry for bi-weekly basis (every other week) .
For example if cron runs on 05/05/2017(Friday) , It should run on 19/05/2017(Friday)

Comment: Seems question already asked here :
[cronjob-every-two-weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055122/cronjob-every-two-weeks) [how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350047/how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week)

Answer (score 0):

Execute the cron every week and test inside the file if do or not something.
For example:

```
<?php
if (date("W")%2 == 0) {
 //do something
} else {
 //wait
}
?>
```

Comment: Actually I have to call the shell(in unix environment) like below(example)
00 07 * * * . ./.profile; cd xxx/export-xxx-qa; ksh export-xxx-wlymp.ksh 

So, need to handle logic in cron entry.
I have to call the shell "export-xxx-wlymp.ksh" bi-weekly basis (every other week)

Comment: Glad to help Balu. Please mark question as answered if you considered it solved.

Answer (score 0):

This should run every friday:

```
0 0 1-31 1-12 5  someScript.sh
```

This will check if it's an odd week:

someScript.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
WEEK_OF_YEAR=`/bin/date +%V`
echo $WEEK_OF_YEAR
if [[ $(($WEEK_OF_YEAR % 2)) -eq 1 ]];
then
  echo "DO SOMETHING" 
fi
```