# Crontab - "bad day-of-week" error, when trying to schedule a task to run each other day-of-week using "dow/2"

Tags: ubuntu, cron, cron-task

I try to schedule a task in Ubuntu 16.04 using crontab:

```
45 2 * * 4/2 sh /var/lib/libvirt/images/backups/backup_res.sh
```

I want it to be executed every other Thursday at 2:45AM.
However, I keep getting bad day-of-week error.
If I remove /2, it works fine.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is:

```
45 2 * * Thu expr `date +\%s` / 604800 \% 2 >/dev/null || sh /var/lib/libvirt/images/backups/backup_res.sh
```

please see this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350047/how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week)

Comment: Sorry, if I was uncluear. What I meant is I need to run the task once every two weeks on Thursday.