# How can I tell renovate to work on the second Tuesday of every month?

Tags: renovate, later-syntax

We do monthly updates of our App, after Microsoft Tuesday, which is the second Tuesday of the month.  I want renovate to also do its updates at this point so both can go together.

I can't find a suitable value for the "schedule" parameter in renovate.json.
What should I use?

I have tried the following, all of which Renovate rejects as unable to parse:

```
      "schedule": [
        "every month on the second tuesday of the month"
      ]
```

```
      "schedule": [
        "every 1 months on the second tuesday of the month"
      ]
```

```
      "schedule": [
        "on the second tuesday of every month"
      ]
```

```
      "schedule": [
        "before 4am on the second tuesday of the month"
      ]
```

```
      "schedule": [
        "before 4am on the second Tuesday of the month"
      ],
```

Comment: Renovate used Later Syntax for this. https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#schedule

Comment: Thanks, but I already found those links and they don't help much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the text parser page, it looks like you cannot do it with Later
https://breejs.github.io/later/parsers.html#text

There are some references to being able to do it with a cron expression (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73490669), but you'd need to test if Renovate supports them. I'd guess not as `#` is probably reserved for comments

You could look at having something else trigger a renovate run (a Lambda) for example, rather than using a cron with in Renovate (assuming you are running your own).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work (you can change the time based on your needs):

```
on the 2nd day instance on tuesday at 6:00
```

it is based on the documentation that renovate uses for parsing the schedule
https://breejs.github.io/later/parsers.html#text

You can install it locally and experiment with different configurations (https://breejs.github.io/later/getting-started.html).