# I like to schedule crontab run alternative Week in Jenkins. Example: If it runs on may 26th 2020 next run should be on June 9th

Tags: linux, jenkins, cron

Right now, The Crontab which I have is doing for every 3 weeks. Ex: May 19th and June 9th.
I want to have to have May 26th and next run should be on June 9th.

00 11 */2 * 2

Comment: I think you want to run every 2nd week now. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350047/how-to-instruct-cron-to-execute-a-job-every-second-week

Comment: Perhaps ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/